# mountvol does not show all hidden partitions in Windows repair and safe mode (for chkdsk purposes)

Tags: chkdsk, recovery-partition

I have a SSD (Windows 10 + recovery + ESP + 2 partitions) and a HDD (25GB factory recovery + Windows 7 + 4 partitions), 8 visible partitions and 3 hidden, so 11 that can be seen in computer management.

I ran `mountvol` in CMD (as administrator) but received 3 different responses in 3 modes.

In windows, there are 12 partitions! `chkdsk` worked for visible partitions but not for hidden ones, it returns "Cannot open volume for direct access" for 4 partitions.

```
chkdsk “\\?\Volume{f7c4bf40-9f93-11e8-8e6a-806b6f7e4963}”
```

In windows repair mode, there are 10. However, `chkdsk` works for 2 extra hidden partitions as well. I copied one of hidden partition addresses, that I had grabbed in Windows test, and tried to use it in this space but `chkdsk` returned "Cannot open volume for direct access."

In Windows safe mode, there are just 9 partitions! And the rest is the same as the repair mode.

What is the reason for these differences? How can I run `chkdsk` for all hidden partitions?

[image]

Comment: Please add the screenshots of the *complete* screen of Disk Management, for both normal and Safe mode, and let us know which is the partition in question.

Comment: how to add pic? is it necessary?

Comment: We need to have facts to help, and images will help. Loading images is done as described [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344851/how-do-you-add-a-screenshot-image-to-your-stack-overflow-post). If you have problems as a new user on our site, load them to [imgur.com](https://imgur.com/) and [Edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1833370/edit) your post to add these links.

Comment: i edited the main question. check the last link.

Comment: Can't you just add two images, each a total/entire Disk Management screen, for both normal and Safe mode?